# variable in TextDomain Gettext & wordpress, bad practice?

Tags: wordpress, localization, gettext

I dont want to manually type in "my_theme_textdomain" or "my_plugin_textdomain" every time.

so instead of

```
$hello =  __( 'Hello, dear user!', 'my-text-domain' );
```

I use

```
$my_txtdomain = "my-text-domain";
$hello =  __( 'Hello, dear user!', $my_txtdomain );
```

I feel like it shouldnt be a problem since $my_txtdomain is essentialy just a string. But is this a bad practice ?

Comment: But what have you _gained_? You are not going to change the value of `$my_txtdomain` during runtime, right?

Comment: Nope. It'll save me the trouble of mass "search & replace" when I duplicate my theme / plugin to make a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it is "kind of" a bad practice, but not really. But it will work. You can read the discussion below:
https://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2011/10/06/translating-wordpress-plugins-and-themes-dont-get-clever/

> And they think to themselves “hm, I sure am typing the
>   'my-plugin-name' string a lot. I’ll apply the DRY (Don’t Repeat
>   Yourself) principle and throw that string into a variable or a
>   constant!”
>
> Stop! You’re being too clever! That won’t work!*

---

> the domain argument isn’t parsed at all. It is used only when the
>   string is translated to choose the correct .mo file and it’s perfectly
>   OK to be a variable.